# Rspec error: undefined local variable or method `cookies' for #<RSpec in the model for Sign_in method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't use any gem for authentication in my app...so my sign_in method looks like this

```
def sign_in(user)
 remember_token = User.new_remember_token
 cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
 user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
 self.current_user = user
end
```

I have this under both app/helpers/session_helper.rb and spec/support/helpers/session_module.rb
I need to call sign_in(user) in my model specs... I get the error **undefined local variable or method `cookies' for**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookies hash is only available in RSpec's controller tests.  You can tell your specs to pretend that they're controller specs by adding type: :request to your context, like so:

```
describe 'something that requires cookies', type: :request do
   it { expect(cookies[:remember_token]).to be_nil } // now the variable is defined as nil.
end
```

That said, needing your models to know about signing in surprises me.  That kind of cross-scope testing usually belongs in a feature.

Answer (score 1):

model spec don't setup a test request context. so you ain't got no cookies dude!

use stubs or mocks here.