# Rspec - NoMethodError: undefined method `cookies' for Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Try to add rspec tests to my App and have following error:

> NoMethodError:
>   undefined method `cookies' for #

Here is my simple code:

```
get :my_action, params: { id: @request.id }
expect(response.status).to eq(200)
```

But I do not use anywhere cookies in my App project. And why 'coockies' try to executes for my Request model object?
What could it be?

PS Request - it is my model (has :title, :description)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I'm getting undefined method \`cookies'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903668/why-im-getting-undefined-method-cookies)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rspec error: undefined local variable or method \`cookies' for #<RSpec in the model for Sign\_in method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490852/rspec-error-undefined-local-variable-or-method-cookies-for-rspec-in-the-mod)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found error... I have own model Request, and I use instance variable in RSpec test like:

```
@request = Request.create(....
```

But RSpec already uses this instant variable:

```
request
=> #<ActionController::TestRequest:0x007fa8d3b54fb8
  @controller_class=RequestsController,
  @custom_param_parsers=
```

The issue was related with rewriting necessary RSpec @request with my data